# How would I go about checking every cell in a column to see if it includes any text string in a cell from another column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am working with a product database in Excel and seeking to clean up and homogenize the way to which manufacturers are referred. The database is about 9k rows so is not friendly to manual editing. There are also some manufacturer names missing in the database--it is not perfect.

The headings for each column are organized as follows:

```
SKU(commercial product code)  |  Commercial Description  |  Manufacturer Name
```

And an example of a row entry would be:

```
MCO20264  |  PAD,BURNISH,27 IN,PK5  |  3M Corp.
```

The goal is to edit the Manufacturer Name column so that every time there is a reference to a manufacturer, for example 3M, whether it be by the entry 3M Corp., 3M Corporation, 3M, etc., it uses a homogeneous name, such as 3M, rather than multiple names. There are about 500 different Manufacturer Names. Many are referred to via multiple names, but when they are, they always include some abbreviated version of their name in the text string, like how 3M always appears in the list above.

I already have some homogenized manufacturer names. The homogeneous manufacturer names that I have are in a column on a separate sheet, and because of how many there are I would like the cells in that column to be referenced rather than including individual text strings of each name in the function.

I seek to exclude any row in my list of **all** manufacturers in which the Manufacturer Name cell contains a text string of a homogeneous name, such as 3M, anywhere in the cell, so that I can work with only those names which lack a homogeneous name to which they could be referred. The ultimate goal is to complete the homogeneous manufacturer names list, and apply it to the database so that each manufacturer is only referred to in one way.

I have tried various ways to include

```
"*"A2"*"
```

type notation in functions to solve this issue, but have had no success including this notation here.

Does anybody know how I could solve my problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the MS's [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx)? Here's a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v-qxcjZbyo) video.

Comment: Are you looking to have the "cleaned" name next to the orginal one, or to replace the entered name with the "cleaned" one?

Comment: Ultimately replace the original. For now I have just been making a list of all the "cleaned" names, which I hope to use to replace the names they homogenized.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using formula, and the SEARCH function, so something like

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("3M",A1,1)>0,"3M",A1),A1)
```

You can modify this to suit your needs.

If you had data in A1:A6 for example, the following array formula would return the rows where 3M is in the text

```
=SMALL(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("3M",$A$1:$A$6,1)>0,0),ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROWS($B$1:$B1))
```

Let me know if I can help further.

EDIT further solution

If you have Data in A1:B4 as your replacement data, so in A the text to replace, in B the replacement, so 3M Corp in A, 3M in B. My columnd of to seach on is D, so have a variety in there like 3M Corp, 3M Asia, Panasonic Plc, Panasonic Ltd, then in E I have the following formula

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$2:$A$4,D2)),-1,ROW($A$2:$A$4)-1)),1)` 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to search for 3M specifically, I want to reference the cells in the list I already have of homogeneous manufacturer names. I have 500 manufacturer names so including any specific text string in the formula would just mean having to repeat that hundreds of times for different text strings.

Comment: You can use an array to search for multiple items, do a bit of reading on arrays, you would use something like c1:c6 where "3M" is, so something like if(search(c1:c6,a1:a6,1)>0,d1:d6) where d1:d6 is the replacement value, sort of a looping vlookup.  I'll try and do something for you.  Not 100% sure i'll have time.

Comment: Tried variations of the formula you suggested and wasn't working. I have one column with Every manufacturer name (non homogenized) and another with the homogenized names I have made so far. WTV function needs to go through the non homogenized list and see for every cell whether and text string in the homogenized list is found within the cell, then either output the cells that do, do not, or indicate in their row whether or not they do or do not.

Comment: Did you fix this?  If you have Data in A1:B4 as your replacement data, so in A the text to replace, in B the replacement, so 3M Corp in A, 3M in B.   My columnd of to seach on is D, so have a variety in there like 3M Corp, 3M Asia, Panasonic Plc, Panasonic Ltd, then in E I have the following formula                                                                                                     =INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$2:$A$4,D2)),-1,ROW($A$2:$A$4)-1)),1)   Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are saying, but those are no quite what I have here. I have Column A2:A560 with the incomplete homogeneous manufacturer names (as in the names I would like to use as homogeneous replacements for the varying names that will appear in column B), and Column B2:B185 with every manufacturer name without consideration to multiple names for the same thing. I am not sure what the code you wrote is doing with column C, D, and E, but I only need one column as an output. If you are suggesting forming another column with something different to help could you please clarify?

Comment: It is what you asked for, I have my replacements in b instead of a.  I used c as a test entry to replace and d with the answer, so in mine i have say, a1 is 3m, b1 is 3m corp, d1 contains 3m Japan inc,  Did you try based on my answer? You need to do some investigations yourself to ;-)

Comment: I am not sure why you have a column c with test entries (not sure where you are getting these or why you would need). You say you put replacements in column b and things to be replaced in a, yet you give the example where a1 contains 3m and b1 contains 3mcorp. which looks like a1 should be replacing b1 because it is an abbreviated version of their name. If d is your answer (answer could say if entry in the column with extra names to be homogenized contains something in the homogeneous column) why are you getting 3m Japan, which isn't simple like 3m (because it contains "Japan" text string)?

Comment: A is what to be replaced b is what to replace it with c is my own test data and d.  I can't offer much more help, have you tried anything yourself? A=3m b=3m corp c= 3m Japan d is then 3m corp. What can't you understand from my edited answer,  it's all there.

Comment: Please see my comment on March 11th for what I don't understand about your approach. It may be clear to you, but evidently there was some miscommunication. I finished the problem myself. I wish I could have made sense of what you were trying to do.